# Gulp task 'scripts' doesn't stop to running its task but other task working fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-watch

Hi everbody I hope everyone is alright during this pandemic. I got 1 issue with my code my but my sass and autoprefixer are working fine only my `scripts` task wont stop whenever I save my `main.js`. I hope everyone can help me with this one. Thank You

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('./scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            errLogToConsole: true,
            outputStyle: 'expanded'
        }))
        .on('error', console.error.bind(console))
        .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 99 versions'], {cascade: true }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// I think my script task its the problem
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('./js/*.js') 
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});    

gulp.task('html', function () {
    return gulp.src('./*.html')
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
    
gulp.task('browserSync', function(){
  
    browserSync.init({
        server : {
            baseDir : './'
        }
    });
    gulp.watch('./scss/**.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
    gulp.watch('./*.html', gulp.series('html'));
    gulp.watch('./js/*.js', gulp.series('scripts'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('sass', 'scripts', 'html', 'browserSync'));
```

My Basic Directory Tree:

```
|-css   
|-img
|-js
     |- main.js
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "horita",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^6.1.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

On terminal you can see below that the task wont end it keeps on `Finished` and `Starting`.

[image]

Comment: Because you are saving into the same file you are watching - so at the end of the `scripts` task it saves the file which triggers `watch` task to start the `scripts` tasks which saves the file which triggers the `scripts` task which...  Save to a different directory.

Comment: Hi @Mark it work's fine when when I save it in a different directory, is it possible to save it in a the same directory? Could you help me thanks

Comment: Anything else is a poor workaround.  Work on `src/js` folder, save to `dist/js` folder.